# Android: Importing certificates is successful, but they don't show up in Trusted Credentials

Tags: android, digital-certificate

I'm trying to import this certificate into Android (4.1): http://www.realmb.com/cert/MNLNPE

When I visit that URL in my Android browser and click the certificate, it says is installs successfully. However, it never shows up in the trusted credentials manager. Can anyone help me troubleshoot that?

Comment: You might want to try mailing yourself the certificate, downloading it and then installing it locally. Are you seeing any credential storage prompts when you try to install the certificate? As far as I know installing certs directly from the browser without any prompts - that should not be happening.